# Loading CSS through JS

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile

I'm trying to load my non-essential CSS through JS using the code Google provides on their page speed analytics site.
The code is:

```
  var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = <?php echo "'css/" . $page . "-mobile.css'"; ?>;
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
```

It seems to work well on safari (desktop and mobile), chrome (desktop and mobile) and mozilla (desktop and mobile). But for some reason the browser Samsung uses for Galaxy S4 and below is not loading the css file (though S5 works as predicted, and loads the CSS).

I tried everything and I just think that the built-in browser samsung uses is just crappy..
Would love for any suggestion that might help here,
Thanks,
Boaz.

Comment: Your code is inserting your `link` element before the `head` element.  Should it?  Try replacing `h.parentNode.insertBefore` with `h.appendChild`.  Or if your css file must be the inserted as the first element of `head`, try `h.insertBefore(l, h.firstChild)`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but it seems the iOS6 doesn't apply the CSS if it's loaded after the page is ready with the appendChild method..Is it a really a good way to solve loading time issues?

Comment: What happens if you replace `else window.addEventListener('load', cb);` with `else cb();`?  I don't see any worthwhile benefit to defer `appendChild` until page load is complete.  If that doesn't satisfy iOS either, then try `document.body.appendChild` and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. The S4 was choking on requestAnimationFrame.

removing:

```
var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
  webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
if (raf) raf(cb);
else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
```

and just using:

```
 window.addEventListener('load', cb);
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after viewing the android browser js errors:

```
about:debug (write it instead the url of the page with the issues)
```

You want to call cb from request animation frame callback, if it exists
adding the checking to each one of them will solve the problem and also 
renderer it using webkitRequestAnimationFrame instead of onload.

```
  var raf = false;
  raf = !raf && typeof (requestAnimationFrame) !== 'undefined' ? requestAnimationFrame : raf;
  raf = !raf && typeof (mozRequestAnimationFrame) !== 'undefined' ? mozRequestAnimationFrame : raf;
  raf = !raf && typeof (webkitRequestAnimationFrame) !== 'undefined' ? webkitRequestAnimationFrame : raf;
  raf = !raf && typeof (msRequestAnimationFrame) !== 'undefined' ? msRequestAnimationFrame : raf;
  if (raf) {
    raf(cb);
  }else {
    window.addEventListener('load', cb);
  }
```